# Square root of a root of unity.

Tags: number-theory, roots-of-unity

Let $n$ be an integer, and let $\zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}$ be a $n$-th root of unity, with $1\le k\le n$. Can someone explain to me why we have the following,

$$
\sqrt{\zeta}=\begin{cases}
  e^{2\pi ik'/n} & \mbox{with}\; 1\le k'\le n,\; \mbox{if}\; n\;\mbox{is odd}\\
  e^{\pi ik'/n} &  \mbox{with}\; 1\le k'\le 2n,\; \mbox{if}\; n\;\mbox{is even}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I changed your formatting to make it more readable, note the `cases` environment, which automates a lot of things you had to put in by hand...

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You're more likely to get an answer rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Hint: start by calculating all those square roots when $n=3$ and then when $n=4$ to confirm the assertion.

Comment: What is the square root of a complex number which is not real and nonnegative? (Old tune, yes...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the square root means to take $1/2$ of the exponent  which leads to other roots of unity.

Observe $\zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}} =e^{\frac{2\pi i(k+n)}{n}}$.  So you have the choice of taking $1/2$ of the exponent either in the first or in the second formulation. Depending on wether $k$ and $n$ are even or odd, you want a consistent formulation where, in the exponent,  $k'$ is indeed a positive integer.

case 1: $n$ is odd. You can indeed satisfy $\sqrt\zeta=e^{\frac{\pi ik}{n}} =e^{\frac{\pi i(k+n)}{n}} = e^{\frac{2 \pi ik'}{n}} $, where $k'$ is  a positive integer, as folows: If $k$ is even, you have $k' = \frac{k}2$. This gives you $1 \le k' \le (n-1)/2$. If $k$ is odd, you have $k' = \frac{k+n}2$. This gives you $(1+n)/2 \le k' \le n$. So you cover $1 \le k' \le n$.

case 2: $n$ is even. Comparing to case 1, you have the problem that for odd $k$, you cannot arrange that, in the exponent,  $k'$ is indeed a positive integer as laid out in case 1. Therefore you need the new formulation
$\sqrt\zeta=e^{\frac{\pi ik}{n}} =e^{\frac{\pi i(k+n)}{n}} = e^{\frac{\pi ik'}{n}} $. Now both choices of either  $k' = k$ or $k' = {k+n}$ solve the equation. So you cover $1 \le k' \le 2n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.